# how convert ISCHANGED and ISBLANK functionalities of WORKFLOW FieldUpdate Action to Apex to update another field value

Tags: apex

```
AND( 
  ISCHANGED(field1)=TRUE, 
  ISBLANK(field1)=FALSE 
)
```

need to update field2=field1.FirstName &" "& field1.LastName

this is used in Workflow,
how can i write in apex on opportunity object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using trigger then you can use :
Oldmap ¡= newmap and for checking isBlank, you can just put null check and then update the value on field.

For checking isChange in Apex.

for(Id recordId : newObjectsMap.keyset()){
if(oldObjectsMap.get(recordId).FieldName__c != (newObjectsMap.get(recordId).FieldName__c){
//your code logic
}
}